# Execute bash inside subshells

Tags: bash, shell-script, nix

Say I have a command that puts me into a subshell (e.g. `nix-shell`). If I have a bash script that goes

```
enter-subshell
echo hi
```

the `echo hi` will wait to be executed until I exit the subshell. Is there any way to write a script that behaves the same as manually typing out both lines in order? In other words, subsequent commands get executed in the newly invoked shell?

Edit: it seems what I'm looking to do doesn't have a general solution.

Comment: what is "enter-subshell"? if it's "nix-shell"  there is a solution. if it is different the may be a different solution.

Comment: Are you looking for the `--run` option to `nix-shell`? `nix-shell --run "echo hi"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a script and invoke that shell calling your script as a parameter. For example:

```
$ echo "echo hi" > my_echo.subshell
$ echo "enter-subshell -c my_echo.subshell" > my_script.bash
$ ./my_script.bash
```

The way to pass parameters to the subshell (in my example "`-c`") will depend on your subshell, each shell might use a different parameter.

As an alternative, if you don't want to create a second script, you can also redirect instructions to the shell. It will also vary and depend on the shell you want to call. For example:

```
enter-subshell -e <<EOF
echo hi
EOF
```

For this method, you can read more on "[Here Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2500451/2193235)". Again, you will find the proper way of executing the specific subshell (in my example "`-e`").

Comment: You're probably going to want `<<'EOF'` for another shell script.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I think parsing of the outside script takes precedence, doesn't it? I'm not sure.